# Spring automatically wrap rest controller response in ResponseEntity

Tags: spring, spring-rest, reactor

Here is what I'm trying to achieve : 
I have many spring rest reactive controller returning various Object such as Mono, Flux

I would like to wrap all these response in a ResponseEntity and so always return something like :

```
Mono<ResponseEntity<MyObjects>>
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Return `ResponseEntity<Mono<MyObjects>>` ?

Comment: this way or the another, but it's not the question, i'm looking for a way to wrap my responses in a ResponseEntity automatically like with a filter or a response handler or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `@ResponseBody` Annotation on your controllers

> When you use the @ResponseBody annotation on a method, Spring converts the return value and writes it to the http response automatically. Each method in the Controller class must be annotated with @ResponseBody.

See [the example](https://www.genuitec.com/spring-frameworkrestcontroller-vs-controller/)

Comment: do you mean it will wrap my response in a ResponseEntity.ok() automatically ?

Comment: Kind of. It returns json representation of the method return object with correct status

Comment: No need for that! `@RestController` automatically annotates methods with `@ResponsyBody` according to the link you provided: `By annotating the controller class with @RestController annotation, you no longer need to add @ResponseBody to all the request mapping methods. The @ResponseBody annotation is active by default. `